# Changed mysql server and got php error, same code, same mysql version

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I have 2 ubuntu servers with MySQL version:

**Server 1:** MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

**Server 2:** MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

The PHP code is on other server and I just change the IP of connection like this
Mysql connect 10.1.1.1
Mysql connect 10.1.1.2

When I connect to MySQL server 10.1.1.1 everything is working and no PHP error messages.

When I connect to mysql server 10.1.1.2 i have this php error:

Command: `number_format(trim($order[$i]['value']), 2, ',', '.')`

Error: `Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given in /home/admin/web/orders.php on line 45`

The server 1 is an old ubuntu installation and server 2 is a new Ubuntu installation.

Server 1 and Server 2 is used only to run MySQL, PHP codes are coming from other servers.

I just did the database backup from server 1 and have restored this backup on server 2.

I tried to see some my.cnf configs but didn't find any differences!

I'm trying to fix it for more than 6 hours, but no way!

Thank you, everyone, for try to help!

Comment: What versions of PHP are the two servers running?

Comment: PHP is the same server, running 5.6, I just changed the IP of mysql connection!

Comment: If you echo $order[$i]['value'] what do you get?

Comment: If i'm connected to the first server, i have so many rows and this value is something like money value... 120,00 / 200,00 / 30,00 and so on!
But if I'm connected to the second server, it gets only 1 row, and this value got 0,00.

Comment: @Zabar Maybe a locale problem? How the numbers with comma is interpreted on the different servers?

Comment: Just updating this to give for someone the right reply. If ubuntu installed with 16.04.3 I have this problem, but if installed using 16.04.4 problem fixed. Then, its something wrong with ubuntu. =)

Answer (score 0):

for avoid the problem  you can use a cast  for float:

```
number_format(floatval( trim($order[$i]['value'])), 2, ',', '.')
```

Comment: With using floatval, I don't have error message anymore, but from the server 1 i have 5 rows in the reply and server 2 only 1 row and wrong results. Wow!

Comment: this clearly  seems   a new  question to  me .. you have asked for a problem and my answer  resolve your problem  ... i can't imagine the content of your database in each server and the code you use  .. so if my answer is correct you should mark it as acceppeted ..  and for the new problem you should post a new properly described  question

Comment: O believe the error is over mysql server or ubuntu configs!

Comment: why ... you thinks this .. seems you are using similar version of OS and this should not affect php behavior ..but what kind of output your expecting?  are you sure you are using same version of PHP ??